# ReactNative Navigation headerRight Toggle Drawer Error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a screen where i have a back button and a menu drawer button on the right

when i click on the menu drawer button i get the error (undefined isn't an object)

the code tried to trigger the toggle.drawer(). it works fine in the render code but it doesn't work in the headerRight here is the code

```
    export default class categoryScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        headerRight:
        <Button 
        onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()} // This Doesn't work how to make it work
        transparent>
            <Icon style={styles.categoryDrawerMenu}type="Entypo" ios='ios-menu' android="menu" color="#1a1917" />
        </Button>,
      drawerIcon: (
        <Icon style={styles.menu}type="AntDesign" name="home" color="#1a1917" />
      )
    }
    render() {
          return (                                                                                                           
            <Container>
                        <Button 
        onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()} // This Works 
        transparent>
            <Icon style={styles.categoryDrawerMenu}type="Entypo" ios='ios-menu' android="menu" color="#1a1917" />
        </Button>
            </Container>
         );                                                                                                                 
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to `this.props` from a static context, you need to access your navigation object like this:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        headerRight:
        <Button 
        onPress={()=> navigation.toggleDrawer()} // This Doesn't work how to make it work
        transparent>
            <Icon style={styles.categoryDrawerMenu}type="Entypo" ios='ios-menu' android="menu" color="#1a1917" />
        </Button>,
      drawerIcon: (
        <Icon style={styles.menu}type="AntDesign" name="home" color="#1a1917" />
      )
    }
```